# Azure Sql dacpac task - Login failed for user '***@<guid>'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-authentication, dacpac

I am trying to deploy Azure SQL DB via dacpac in Azure Devops pipeline. I get the below error,

> Unable to connect to target server
> '[servername].database.windows.net'. Please verify the connection
> information such as the server name, login credentials, and firewall
> rules for the target server.  **Login failed for user** **'****@some guid'**
> The Azure SQL DACPAC task failed. SqlPackage.exe exited with code 1.

I executed below queries as SQL server Admin.

```
CREATE USER [service principal] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [service principal]
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [service principal]
GRANT VIEW Definition TO [service principal]
GRANT ALTER ON DATABASE :: [Database name] TO [service principal]
```

Azure Devops pipeline task

```
task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
        displayName: 'Azure SQL Dacpac Task'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: '[azureSubscription]'
          AuthenticationType: 'servicePrincipal'
          ServerName: '$(servername).database.windows.net'
          DatabaseName: '$(Database)'
          DacpacFile: '$(DacpacPath)'
          AdditionalArguments: '/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false /p:DropObjectsNotInSource=true /p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Users;Logins;RoleMembership;Permissions'
```

Answer (score 1):

***I tried the SQLdacpac deployment task in Azure Devops yaml pipeline and it was successful, Refer below:-***

SQLdacpac deployment task [**link**](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlAzureDacpacDeploymentV1/README.md)

**My yaml pipeline script:-**

```yaml
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'AzureSQL'
    AuthenticationType: 'servicePrincipal'
    ServerName: 'siliconserver.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'silicondb'
    deployType: 'DacpacTask'
    DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
    DacpacFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Database1.dacpac'
    IpDetectionMethod: 'IPAddressRange'
    StartIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
    EndIpAddress: '255.255.255.255'
```

**Output:-**

***Dacpac deployment was successful***

[image]

I created the Service connection in Azure Devops with the same service principal I added as a user external provider in my Azure SQL DB, Refer below:-

[image]

This is my service principal whose Client Id and client Secret I used above and added it as an owner in my Azure SQL.

[image]

Powershell Service principal has an Owner role at the Subscription level, you can add it as an Owner or contributor at the Azure SQL server level too.

[image]

Ran the SQL script from your question and added the powershell service principal in my Azure SQL database as external provider with DB roles.

In order to resolve your error, Make sure you have added your Client IP or added below Firewall rules in your Azure SQL.

[image]

**In my pipeline:-**

```yaml
IpDetectionMethod: 'IPAddressRange'
    StartIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
    EndIpAddress: '255.255.255.255'
```

*Make sure the servername of your Azure SQL is correct and does not have any syntax missing or extra in the variable where its saved.*

**My servername:-**

```yaml
    ServerName: 'siliconserver.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'silicondb'
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to queries mentioned in question, I had to execute the below as well.

```
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [service principal]
```