# How do I connect to an Azure SQL database using sqlcmd and a service principal?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create user accounts in a database that's being created in an Azure DevOps deployment pipeline.

I have a service principal assigned as the Azure AD Admin for the database server. I'm now attempting to log in to the database using that service principal so that I can create the necessary user accounts.

Looking at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=odbc#activedirectoryserviceprincipal) it seems as though only the 'go' version of sqlcmd supports connecting using a service principal, but the Azure DevOps Linux agent only has the 'odbc' version of sqlcmd installed.

I really don't want to have to deal with the inefficiency and fragility of having to install additional tools on the build agent for every run.

How can I run SQL queries on an Azure SQL database from a build agent using a service principal?

<s>I'm pretty sure I can do it easily enough using SQL authentication, but apparently that's not best practice anymore.</s>
SQL logins can't be used to create AD logins, so that won't work anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76288815/azure-sql-dacpac-task-login-failed-for-user-guid/76315161#76315161 check if this helps you?